# ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group on WildFly 19.1 using Java 14

Tags: java, wildfly, jaas, java-ee-8, java-14

I migrated a [Web application](https://github.com/dwws-ufes/marvin) that worked fine on WildFly 17 on Java 11 to the latest versions of both: WildFly 19 on Java 14. In the end I'm getting a `ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group`, probably because the Web application uses JAAS.

Note that a similar Web application built following [a tutorial of my own](https://github.com/dwws-ufes/jbutler/wiki/Tutorial00) worked fine, but it doesn't use JAAS. That and the package `java.security.acl` made me think JAAS is related.

Searching the Web I found [issue WFCORE-4282 at WildFly's JIRA](https://jira.jboss.org/projects/WFCORE/issues/WFCORE-4282) which seems to imply that although they knew this `java.security.acl.Group` class was deprecated more than a year ago, WildFly 19 still requires it and Java 14 did actually remove it, thus causing the `ClassNotFoundException` for me.

Is my interpretation correct? Does WildFly 19 + Java 14 + JAAS = `ClassNotFoundException` necessarily or has anyone managed to make it work? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong? It just seems to me such a huge problem for JBoss to have overlooked on WildFly...

**Update**: I removed Java 14, installed Java 13, reinstalled Eclipse and WildFly and redeployed de application and it worked, so WildFly 19 + Java 13 + JAAS = OK!

Comment: Hi Vitor, did you ever find a solution to this that didn't involve downgrading to Java 13? As you said, it seems such a huge problem.

Comment: Hi @RichardKennard, since my use for these things is for educational purposes (I'm a college professor and I teach Web Development to undergrad/grad students), I downgraded to Java 13 for this to work at that time and in the next semester I ended up migrating to Jakarta Security, so I didn't have further issues with this. Sorry I can't be of more help here.

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved as of late 2021 (better late than never!). So you can now use JDK 17+ with WildFly 26+. Note, however, you have to make the non-trivial move from:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
...
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
...
</login-module>
</subsystem>
```

...to...

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:wildfly:elytron:15.0">
...
<security-realms>
    <jdbc-realm>
    ...
    </jdbc-realm>
</security-realms>
</subsystem>
```

YMMV depending on your architecture, but basically you have to embrace Elytron.

Answer (score 1):

The java.security.acl API was terminally deprecated and has been removed in Java 14: see release notes:

https://jdk.java.net/14/release-notes

Comment: Yeah, that was what op said in the question.

Comment: Which means that Vitor's interpretation was correct which was the question ;-) But maybe I misread that - if so apologies for the noise.

Comment: Thanks, @daniel. My interpretation goes further: not only it was deprecated but the WildFly developers did nothing about it. The counter-interpretation is that *I* am doing something wrong. Releasing a version of WildFly that just won't work with Java 14 and JAAS is a huge problema IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

**Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group**
19:23:14,951 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] (default I/O-11) AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group

**Please try following workaround  update standalone.xml and restart Server**

add xml tag `<security enabled="false"/>`

```xml
<server name="default">
<security enabled="false"/>
<statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
<security-setting name="#">
    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
</security-setting>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that disable JAAS on my Web application? I would like to keep using it.